# Is there any other way to order or sort by in php query for sql data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I am trying to order by with specfic column in sql data but it is not working, here is the query.

```
query = mysql_query("SELECT A, B FROM tableAAA WHERE C = 'Slected' ORDER BY D")
```

Could you please tell any other way of sorting or ordering?

Comment: How is it now working? Can you show example data and output?

Comment: In your example you are trying to order by D but you have not selected D.  You can only order by rows that have been selected.  So SELECT A, B From table A WHERE C = 'blah' ORDER BY A would work because it exists as part of the result set

Comment: Not true - a column does *not* have to be part of the SELECT clause to be used in the ORDER BY clause.  Aside from the apparent misspelling of "Selected" in the WHERE clause, there isn't any problem with the query.

Comment: Are you sure you want `WHERE C = 'Slected'` and not `WHERE C = 'Selected'`

Comment: No  **selected** is just for refference. i am using something else

Comment: Is it possible that 'ORDER BY' only works for large data, if yes then what would be alternative for small table

Comment: @wiki NO, Order By works even on one result